# Changing CSS class of a component with ngClass if some data is null or undefined

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In my app, I have several components like buttons, boxes with some text, etc. Some of them need to get an additional CSS class and get disabled only if some data is null or undefined. I've tried to make it as below, but it didn't work. Is there any better way to solve this?

The example below returns "Cannot read property 'result' of undefined" error.

```
[ngClass]="{data.result.policyData === null ? '-disabled' : ''}"
```

Now in this one, I am getting an error that only string can be attached to ngClass.

```
[ngClass]="setDisabledClass()"

setDisabledClass() {
  let cssClass;
  this.checkResults.subscribe(data => {
    if (data.result.policyData === null) {
      cssClass = {
        '-disabled': true
      };
    } else {
      cssClass = {
        '-disabled': false
      };
    }
    return cssClass;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as well:

TS:

```
enableBtn: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
this.checkResults.subscribe(data => {
  if (data.result.policyData === null) {
    this.enableBtn = true;
  } else {
    this.enableBtn = false;
  }
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="create-apply-btn" [ngClass]="setDisabledClass() ? 'create-apply-btn 
 active': 'create-apply-btn'" (click)="send()">Send</button>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

https://angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix.stackblitz.io

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great to here from you... The first example will also be useful in many scenario. I was just showing a simple example by toggling a property.

Answer (score 0):

The below example will help you:

HTML:

```
<button class="create-apply-btn active" (click)="enable()">Enable</button>
<button class="create-apply-btn active" (click)="disable()">Disable</button>
<br>
<h5>Result:</h5>
<button [ngClass]="enableSave() ? 'create-apply-btn active': 'create-apply-btn'" 
 (click)="send()">Send</button>
```

TS:

```
name = "Angular";
enableButton: boolean = false;

enableSave() {
 return this.enableButton;
}
enable() {
 this.enableButton = true;
}
disable() {
 this.enableButton = false;
}
send(){
 console.log('Button clicked and is enabled.')
}
```

CSS:

```
.create-apply-btn {
font-size: 14px;
border: initial;
background: #eaeaea;
color: #999999;
padding: 0px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0 4% 0;
text-align: center;
height: 42px;
pointer-events: none;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.create-apply-btn.active {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
pointer-events: all;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please find the sample demo:

https://angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope this example will help you. For you there is some logic that can implement referring this example.

Comment: Thank you! But actually, my main issue here - is that data is not being read correctly, and the expression returns errors all the time. In my other components with ngClass (without data.result condition), everything works perfectly...

Comment: You need to have the subscription in ngOnInit() and set a property true if defined, else false. The return this value (property) in setDisabledClass() method. Use this syntax:<button [ngClass]="enableSave() ? 'create-apply-btn active': 'create-apply-btn'" 
 (click)="send()">Send</button>